# Термин "контекст"

Tags: java, c#, терминология, context

Я бы хотел четко для себя сформулировать понятие контекста.

В качестве примеров можно взять контекст из EntityFramework и Spring. Я бы сказал, что это репрезентация окружения, но не уверен в точности этого определения, так как в каком-нибудь спринге - это вероятно так, так как контекст там позволяет выбрать, какое окружение поднять (сервлет, реактив, т.д.), а в EF - инстанс DBContext - это основной способ создания запросов к базе, т.е. контекст здесь уже выходит за пределы репрезентации окружения.

P.S. да, в спринге тоже можно через контекст вытянуть Бин, но это считается антипаттерном и служит для внутренних целей.

Comment: Очень часто пользуюсь абстракцией "контекста", для себя формулирую как набор переменных, задание которых позволяет чётко задать [по возможности минимальные] границы того, что понадобится методу/классу для работы. Для меня контекст настолько часто идёт рука об руку с "состоянием", что я даже подумываю, что это во многом созвучные термины.

Comment: @AK в принципе согласен, я просто немного озадачен тем, что через контекст в EF нужно манипулировать базой.

Comment: Если вы будете думать о DbContext не как о базе, а как о [классе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10776121/5752652), который реализует [паттерн Unit of Work](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), то имху всё становится на свои места.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим пример из реальной жизни. Допустим вы купили билет в солнечную страну и прибыли в аэропорт (скажем, Домодедово) намереваясь вылететь и предъявляете посадочный талон на входе в заветную зону посадки и тынц, вас не пускают, потому что посадочный талон у вас от Шереметьево (да, бывает такое). Посадочный талон привязан к Шереметьево, для него *контекстом* является Шереметьево, но не Домодедово. С равным неуспехом, посадочный талон не примут у вас ни в метро, ни на электричке и вообще нигде кроме конкретного аэропорта Домодедово, который и является контекстом.

*Контекст* аэропорта Домодедово, включает в себя безусловно не только вывеску ДОМОДЕДОВО, но также и посадочную зону, сканеры штрихкодов привязанные к конкретному серверу аэропорта, в БД которого есть ссылка с записью вашего полета и ФИО пассажиров, девушку, которая открывает вам турникет, сам самолет куда вы садитесь, в общем сотни или даже тысями параметров, без которых ваш запрос на посадку в виде посадочного талона не может быть обработан.

В программировании  все аналогично реальной жизни: контекст это набор состояний окружения, в которых будет работать тот или иной запрос/метод. Если угодно `handle/идентификатор/токен`, который обозначает набор состояний среды. В случае примера из реальной жизни таковым токеном является [Домодедово - DME](https://www.world-airport-codes.com/russia/domodedovo-4911.html)

Comment: Согласен, но само по себе состояние(тобишь контекст) не должно обладать функциональностью, оно должно быть состояние, т.е. хранить данные, на основании которых, другие сервисы поймут, что им делать. Разве нет?

Comment: @kaylil_01 Нет. Если исходить из приведённого примера, то регистрация, проверка багажа, таможенный контроль, посадка в самолёт - всё это обладает некой функциональностью. Другие сервисы, на сколько я понимаю, не должны реализовывать логику на основании контекста.